# Interaction of data between View and Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view

My Controller function and variable "money"

```
static int? money = 500;

public ActionResult SubmitPurchase(int? orderPrice)
    {
        money = money - orderPrice;

        ViewBag.Money = money;

        if (db.Purchases.Any())
        {
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from PurchaseLists");
            return View();
        }
        else return RedirectToAction("Order");
    }
```

My View

```html
<div align="center">
    <p><h1>Thank you!</h1></p>
    <p><h2>Your balance is @ViewBag.Money</h2></p>
    <p><h2>Come again plz! :)</h2></p>
</div>
<a href="/Home/Order">
    <input type="button" value="main menu"/>
</a>
```

Another view sends by URL value `orderPrice` in function `SubmitPurchase`. My problem is that `@ViewBag.Money` in My View dosen't shown, but should show value of variable `money` after calculating in function `SubmitPurchase`. What I do wrong?

Comment: check `orderPrice`... if it's null, money will be null

Comment: @mxmissile No, it isn't null because when I call my View I have URL like that - `http://localhost:61314/Home/SubmitPurchase/49`

Comment: Have you confirmed that in the debugger?

Comment: one second i will check

Comment: Yes it's null in debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not passing a valid integer value to the `orderPrice` parameter, your code will try to execute `500-null` which results in `null` and null value will be stored in `money` variable and will be set to ViewBag.

You can do a null check before doing the maths to prevent this happening.

```
if(orderPrice!=null)
    money = money - orderPrice;
```

The url you are trying  to access is http://localhost:61314/Home/SubmitPurchase/49 . With the default MVC route registration, It will not map to the `orderPrice` parameter of your method. You can either update the code to have the url to be generated like

http://localhost:61314/Home/SubmitPurchase?orderPrice=49

**Or**
update your action method parameter name to be `id`

```
 public ActionResult SubmitPurchase(int? id)
 {
    if(id!=null)
        money = money - id;
     // do something
    return View();
 }
```

---

Assuming your SubmitPurchaseview (`SubmitPurchase.cshtml`) has the code to read the ViewBag item and display it.

Comment: No, my code reutrns View. So that page works, but i have a string - 
| **Your balance is** |, but it should be for example like - | **Your balance is 445** |

Comment: Whic view file has your code which displays the ViewBag item ?

Comment: the view that have the same name with the function in controller

Comment: I will check your code and answer will it work or not

Comment: It's mystic, but when i change value name to `id` it starts working, why it works only if name value is `id`? And also thank you very much)

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer, with the default MVC route registration, It will map the parameter value to a parameter with name `id`. If you open up your RouteConfig file's `RegisterRoutes` method, you will be able to see the route registration. So when you access yourSite/controllername/actionmethodname/45, it will map the value 45 to the parameter named id. If you use a different name for your method parameter, update your url to pass it explcitily with the param name as the query string name, or you can use attribute routing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for example:

```
if(orderPrice.HasValue)
{
    money = money - orderPrice;
}
ViewBag.Money = money;
```

Or change your action argument to non-nullable.

```
public ActionResult SubmitPurchase(int orderPrice)
```

Comment: I will try and after will answer